# In Intellij-IDEA, how do I open a browser after a bash script runs?

Tags: java, bash, intellij-idea

With the glassfish configuration, I can launch a browser after the app deploys:

[image]

Is there a way to do this on other types of configurations, namely the bash configuration?  I'm deploying to a remote server with my bash script and would like to open a browser to the site after the deploy finishes.  I suppose I could write this into the bash script itself, but I'd prefer to do this as an intellij feature.

I am using the paid version of intellij 13.

Comment: I don't really understand your reasons for not using the bash to open it.

Comment: Well he could share his configuration, and the other user could still use his own browser.